# Time derivative of $\rm{atan2}$ when $x=0$

Tags: coordinate-systems, velocity, differentiation, geometry, angular-velocity

I want to take the time derivative of the $\rm{atan2}$ function to calculate an azimuth rate in spherical coordinates, given position and velocity in Cartesian $xyz$ coordinates.

$$\rm{atan2}(y, x) =
\begin{cases}
\arctan\bigg(\dfrac{y}{x}\bigg),  & x>0 \\[2ex]
\arctan\bigg(\dfrac{y}{x}\bigg) + \pi,  & x<0, \text{ }\text{ } y\ge 0 \\[2ex]
\arctan\bigg(\dfrac{y}{x}\bigg) - \pi,  & x<0, \text{ }\text{ } y< 0 \\[2ex]
+\dfrac{\pi}{2},  & x=0, \text{ }\text{ } y>0 \\[2ex]
-\dfrac{\pi}{2},  & x=0, \text{ }\text{ } y<0 \\[2ex]
\text{undefined},  & x=y=0
\end{cases}
$$

For the first three rows of the piecewise function, the derivative is straightforward to calculate, and I get $\dfrac{x\dfrac{dy}{dt} - y\dfrac{dx}{dt}}{x^2 + y^2}$.

The next two rows are even easier to calculate, since they're just derivatives of constants, so zero.

Huh?

That is counterintuitive. If an object has $x=0$, it is directly in front of the observer. Why does that make the object have an azimuth rate of zero? An object can whip by in front of my face, and it has an azimuth rate when it is directly in front of me but moving right to left.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where you'd actually need limits.
Consider

$$
f(x):=
\begin{cases}
(x-1)^2,\quad x\neq 0 \\
1,\quad x=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Notice how $f(x)$ is identically equal to $g(x)=(x-1)^2$. However, if you simply differentiate each piecewise component, you run end up with $f'(0)=0$, whereas $g'(0)=-2$. That's a clear contraction.

However, if you were to differentiate $f(x)$ around $x=0$ using the limit, we'd end up with the correct answer.

Comment: The limit $x\rightarrow 0$ does not exist for the $arctan(y/x)$, so my temptation is to use the derivative I gave in my question and just plug in $x$ and $y$. There is no issue with a zero denominator, so long as $y\ne 0$.

Comment: @Dave The atan2 function is neither continuous nor differentiable across the line $x=0$, reflecting the fact that polar coordinates are not well-behaved on the entirety of the punctured plane $\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$.  This is not a statement about physics, only about coordinates.  You'd have to use another chart - perhaps one which is undefined on the negative $x$-axis rather than the positive $x$-axis - in order to calculate the velocity for points where $x=0$.

Comment: @J.Murray but being practical about things - the failure to be continuous is because the angle can 'jump' by $2\pi$. Simply ignoring these constant offsets is going to be physical in this calculation so the overall answer to the OP is just that the formula they give is valid at all x,y (other than the origin of course).

Comment: @jacob1729 Sure.  But this calculation has an immediate and obvious physical interpretation.  In less-intuitive circumstances (GR, QM, etc), exactly the same coordinate issues give rise to problems and contradictions which cannot be so confidently swept away by physical argument.  That being the case, I adopt the perspective that it's useful to point out these mathematical issues when the resolution is obvious, so we're prepared for those circumstances in which it isn't.

Comment: This may be of use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989877/continuous-differentiability-of-atan2/989939#989939